# C++ How to debug a WM/DE or X.org crash?

Tags: window-manager, debugging, c++, crash

I have a huge code that deals with sockets, threads and processes and it is a complete mess... While editing recently, my WM crashed after I executed my code. Since every window is killed, I can't debug my code in a way I am used to... I have never had such situations where my program crashes other processes, so I don't know how to approach this. Do WM's or X.org save their crash reports somewhere so I can take a look? My WM is i3.